# Why my C program stops running in the middle?

Tags: c, memory, dynamic-memory-allocation

I am trying to calculate the minimum coin denomination using the dynamic programming approach, but my code stops running after the 2nd query even though it should run for 10 times if I provide T = 10. Why is it stopping?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int min(int x, int y)
{
    return (x < y) ? x : y;
}

short int min_denom(short int N)
{
    short int *table, i, j, x;
    table = (short int*)malloc(N * sizeof(short int));
    for(i = 0; i < N; i++)  
        table[i] = 1 + i;
    for(i = 1; i <= (short int)sqrt(N); i++)    
        for(j = 0; j < N; j++)      
            if(j == i)
                table[j] = min(1, table[j]);
            else if(j > i)
                table[j] = min(table[j - i - 1] + 1, table[j]);         
    x = table[N - 1];
    free(table);
    return x;               
}

int main()
{
    short int T, N, i;
    scanf("%d", &T);
    for(i = 1; i < T; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &N);
        printf("%d\n", min_denom((short int)N));        
    }
    scanf("%d", &N);
    printf("%d\n", min_denom((short int)N));
         
    return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
10
100
10
500
22
```

Then it stops running automatically.

Comment: Why you are using `short int` instead of `int`? Is this MCU with KB of memory? If not - you have tons of RAM.

Comment: You should be using `"%hd"` instead of `"%d" for `short int`.

Comment: @i486 I just want my program to use less memory, that's it!

Comment: If you specify `%d`, scanf() will store a four-byte integer in a two-byte short int variable. The remaining two bytes will clobber the next  variable on the stack.

Comment: @ThomasJager yes it worked! Thank you so much!

Comment: @r3mainer Yes, Now I understood the technicality behind this problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The code will run till the end if we just replace "%d" either with "%hd" or "%hi". The reason is since the input we are taking will be stored in a short int type of variable, so we must use the proper access specifier for that.

The changed portion is given below.

```
 short int T, N, i;
 scanf("%hi", &T);
 for(i = 1; i < T; i++)
 {
     scanf("%hi", &N);
     printf("%hi\n", min_denom((short int)N));        
 }
 scanf("%hi", &N);
 printf("%hi\n", min_denom((short int)N));
```